# Severe wind has stripped leaves from lemon & lime tree

Tags: lemons, wind-damage

I purchased a lemon and a lime tree and potted in Autumn this year.   They are in full sun and have been looking great however we have had some severe winds and this has stripped the leaves from the trees. Both of them.    They look like they have new leaves coming from the buds on the branches, purple in colour, will they survive, should I prune them back, fertilise them?

Comment: The purple buds may be flowers

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Most trees have the carbohydrate reserves to grow two nearly-full sets of leaves in one year.   They typically don't have reserves to grow a third.  So as long as you don't get a second similar storm in a month or two, the trees should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

A few stripped leaves is not a disaster.Purple leaves are the result of anthocyanins, chemicals in premature leaves that protect it from UV damage til they grow.
Keeping the tree healthy; Lemon tree's love full sun. Most citrus trees need 8-12 hours of light a day. Keep you lemon healthy with a citrus fertilizer. NPK ratio of 6-3-3